# How do I set a list as value for a salt grain?

Tags: salt-stack

How exactly can I use [`salt.modules.grains.set)`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.grains.html#salt.modules.grains.set) to configure a grain which is a list?

Concretely I want to configure the grain `roles` to be a list of roles

```
roles:
  - k8s_node
  - my_role
```

I know I could configure the grains-file, but I explicitly would like to know how to achieve this via the command mentioned above.

I tried different things, none worked. Example

```
sudo salt $node grains.set "roles" k8s_node,my_role
node:
    ----------
    changes:
        ----------
        roles:
            k8s_node,my_role
    comment:
    result:
        True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately figured, you can use  `[xxx]`. So

```
sudo salt $node grains.set "roles" [k8s_node,my_role]
node:
    ----------
    changes:
        ----------
        roles:
            - k8s_node
            - my_role
    comment:
    result:
        True
```